# How to address user by it's first name in telegram bot?

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, py-telegram-bot-api

I'm using pyTelegramBotApi (telebot)

And what I need is to welcome user using it's first name after user press /start

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_command(message):
    bot.send_message(
        message.chat.id, 'Welcome!')
```

This just sends message `Welcome!`, but I need it to look like `Welcome, %first_name%!`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `message` object contains many info about the user;
To get the first_name use; `message.from_user.first_name`

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot("TOKEN")

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def send_welcome(message):

    bot.reply_to(message, "Hi " + message.from_user.first_name + "!")

bot.polling()
```

if you're curious about all the options, the easiest way is to `print()` the object;

```
def send_welcome(message):
    print(message.from_user)
```